# Accessing SQL Server over an SSH tunnel

Tags: sql-server, ssh, ssh-tunnel

In my development shop, we deploy code on virtual servers that sit on a remote network.

We access the machines on that network by first opening an SSH connection to a gateway server, and then SSH-tunneling RDP over a local port.

I would very much like to be able to locally access SQL Server instances running on these servers in the same way.

I've set up a local port (3398) to redirect to the SQL Server port on the remote instance (L3398 -> remote.machine.com:1433).

I can then actually test the connection by telnetting to localhost 3398, and I get a connection: the screen clears and I can type characters to some listening process.

But when I try to connect SSMS to localhost:3398, it times out and then claims that there is no SQL Server listening on that port:

```
Cannot connect to localhost:3398

Additional information:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection 
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
connections. (...)
```

I am sure that the server accepts remote connections, because I have connected to it remotely while logged in via RDP to a different machine within the remote network.

I have Googled around to know that this is possible; does anyone have some idea why this isn't working, or what I might do to diagnose and hopefully fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume wherever you typed 3393 you meant 3398?  I tried to edit it, but there are only 2 characters worth of typos and to submit an edit, you have to make at least 8 characters of changes.  Pretty sure the OP can make small edits, though.

Comment: Updated all 3393s to 3398s.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Instead of connecting to localhost:3398
Use 127.0.0.1,3398

Comment: `localhost,3398` will also work. The important thing is that the port and host are separated by comma, not by colon.

Comment: `localhost` didn't work for me, but `127.0.0.1` is just fine. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Just to add to this: localhost may resolve to IPv6 ::1 depending on your network setup etc. The default IPv6 support depends on your MySQL version: 

From the MySQL 5.6 docs  ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ipv6-support.html ): "As of MySQL 5.6.6, the default MySQL server configuration permits IPv6 connections in addition to IPv4 connections. Before 5.6.6, the default is to permit only IPv4 connections."

Comment: Thank you! Just rounded off a 2 hour search to fix.

Answer (score 1):

For Authentication type `Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA` (Mutli-Factor Authentication), in addition to specifying the port correctly (`127.0.0.1,3398`), I also had to point the host to `localhost`.

On Windows, I had to edit my `hosts` file to include the server host:

```
127.0.0.1    server.example.com
```

Then, in SSMS, I could connect to `server.example.com,3398`, which would perform the MFA correctly.

I could have performed this redirection at a higher DNS level as well.

Comment: I realize this Question has had an Accepted Answer for 8 years, and I don't intend to change that. However, this answer can help anyone who encounters the same problems I was having with MFA.

Comment: You can use other values in /24 too ?  Or install an addtional local loopback.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that SSMS is trying to access the SQL Server Browser Service, which is UDP port 1434. Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx for an overview of the additional ports you may need to forward to get this to work.

Comment: `The SQL Server Browser service listens for incoming connections to a named instance and provides the client the TCP port number that corresponds to that named instance. Normally the SQL Server Browser service is started whenever named instances of the Database Engine are used. The SQL Server Browser service does not have to be started if the client is configured to connect to the specific port of the named instance.`

It sounds like this is a "lookup" service in case there are multiple instances running on multiple ports. I have only one instance running on the default port, 1433.

Comment: Well, that's true, but did you configure SSMS to connect to the specific port of the named instance? By default SSMS will try and browse: I'm uncertain if there is a clean way to disable that behavior.

Comment: In the "Server name:" field, I am specifying "localhost:3398".  Since my local port 3398 maps to port 1433 on the remote machine, that _should_ be constitute specifying the port of the remote instance, right? In any case, I don't think the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the remote machine.

Comment: To specify a port number, the format is "hostname,portnum".  That is, separate them with a comma; you used a colon.

Comment: That's very helpful to know (silly Microsoft!).  Sadly, it didn't solve my problem, though.  I'm pretty sure it's a network issue of some kind.

Comment: I'm curious: if you run SSMS on the server itself, does it work?

Comment: Actually, that did help a bit. Now the error message is "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." Perhaps it's the firewall on the machine, but I can use other DB servers on the remote network to connect to the machine, so ... not sure. Anyway that's a little progress, thanks!

Comment: @Femi: yes. We have four machines on the remote network that are running SQL Server, and, when logged into one of those machines, I can connect to the other three using SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I figured out the answer to this, actually.

On the remote network (which we don't control), for security purposes, it appears that the database servers are set up to ignore database requests coming from the gateway machine. So I guess there's just no good solution short of convincing them to give us full VPN access.  Thanks everyone for your help.