# ODBC via ssh tunnel to a 3rd machine

Tags: ssh, odbc, openssh, unixodbc

At work we have a SqlServer database that cannot be connected to from outside our internal network.  If we want to work remotely we can ssh into several other servers on our network and then work via X Forwarding so the development applications have access to the database.

This is annoying for a bunch of obvious reasons such as latency in the IDE and I'm wondering how I could tunnel the database connnections back to my machine.  It seems like this should be possible but I'm not sure how to do it since there's has to be an intermediate step in between.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915472/accessing-sql-server-over-an-ssh-tunnel) question is similar to what I want to do but only works for going directly to the db server if I understand it correctly.

I'm asking specifically about ODBC because that's the driver the application already uses.  If there is a more general solution I would of course be open to that.

What I want to do is

```
Local machine (Linux) -> Server (Linux) -> Database connection to DB (Sql Server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you say, if you wanted to directly use a encrypted connection to SQL Server you could just use Linux driver that give you that, and most I think do. You could use a bridge as already suggested. But It might be possible using socat. What driver are you using on the local machine? I will have a quick play and see how it works.

Comment: Yep, seems to work with socat. using (on the middle machine) "socat TCP4-LISTEN:1057,fork TCP4:192.168.0.26:1057" allows you to connect to the middle machine from outside, and then that connects onwards to the SQL Server instance listening on 192.168.0.26:1057 (the SQL Server machine). You can of course add your own addresses as required.

Comment: Great this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com) - [Multi-tier ODBC Driver for SQL Server](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver-mt/) might help you out here...

It has a client server architecture as which can easily be configured in a three-tier (client/proxy/server) architecture as follows --

- Linux Client -

  - ODBC Application
  - OpenLink Generic ODBC Driver (Multi-tier client component)
- Linux Proxy -

  - OpenLink Request Broker (Multi-tier server component)
  - OpenLink Database Agent for SQL Server (Multi-tier server component)
- Windows Server -

  - SQL Server DBMS

Comment: I'll look into that some more, it looks a little heavy though.  I was looking for a pretty lightweight solution since this is purely for convenience during development.