# Connect to SQL Server 2016 via Putty/SSH

Tags: sql-server, ssh, putty

I have an SSH tunnel established to my Server using Putty. I have set up two tunnels:

```
L3407 => 192.168.100.107:3389
L31433 => 192.168.100.107:1433
```

I can successfully RDP into the server using "localhost:3407".  However, when I open SSMS and try using "localhost,31433" it won't connect.  The error I get reads:

"A network-realted or instance-speciffic error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1225)"

I've verified that TCP/IP is turned on in SQL Server Configuration Manager, and the IP addresses are setup.  I have checked the logs on the SQL Server, and I have:

```
- Server is listening on [127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434]
- Server is listening on [::1 <ipv6> 1434]
- Server is listening on ['any' <ipv4> 1433]
- Server is listening on ['any' <ipv6> 1433]
```

I can connect to SSMS on the server using the machine name (named pipes),(LOCAL), localhost, 192.168.100.107, or the public IP.  And if I open a hole in the Firewall for port 1433, then I can connect locally using ":1433".  (Of course I almost immediately start seeing hacking attempts, so it has to be turned right back off.)

Based on the error I would think that the server is blocking it somehow, but the local Firewall is off and the hardware Firewall logs no attempts for RDP or SSMS (as expected, since it is going through the tunnel).

I am lost on what else to try. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your tunnel sounds like it's set up correctly and obviously your SQL Server is working as expected. Reading up on this it sounds like folks have good luck when specifying the non-default port by also including the instance name like `thedatabaseserver\mydatabase,31443` One example even suggested specifying the protocol like `tcp:thedatabaseserver\mydatabase,31443` I'm not sure if either of those will work since I've never tried tunneling a SQL Server connection, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: @JNevill I hadn't seen anything like that in all my searches, so I tried it just for the heck of it.  But it doesn't really make sense since it is Putty that takes over the request and directs the traffic through the Tunnel. Using the DB Server in the server name field, at least in this case, would prevent Putty from receiving it & handling it.

Comment: I agree that it seems like it shouldn't make a difference, but I disagree with your assessment of what SMSS is going to send Putty. Mostly because Putty has nothing to do with the the SMSS gui, nor the Tunnel after it's opened. It's just sniffing for local traffic on the 31433 port and shoving it blindly through the tunnel that is set up. Nothing is "Sent' to it. So it might just be that you have must specify TCP traffic and because it's not a default port possibly also the instance name using microsoft's beloved backslash. Agreed though... doesn't seem like it would make a difference.

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325691/1514875 fixed it for me. Had to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`